# How send signals (trigger events) through all browser tabs using JS or JQuery/JS framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many open tabs of my website in browser. How I can send signals (trigger events) through all of them, maybe somebody knows good article/blogpost about that? Example: in  one tab I will be login to the site, after some seconds user interface in other tabs must be changed. What advice **is best practice** to perform this case? 
Sorry for bad English language, I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Object.observe (on chrome) and session storage maybe. But would be better to use websockets on a server for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), a data store in the browser that's shared among all tabs/windows that are viewing the same domain.  There's a `storage` event that is triggered in all tabs when any tab makes a storage change.  There's a demo here: http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have your server handle that. (e.g. you notify your server when you login and your server tells communicates tot the other opened tabs). NodeJS and websockets can do that easily but that depends on what you use/ are comfortable with for your server language.